# Viewing all images in asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, asset-pipeline

I am having trouble with viewing images correctly on my web browser. I inputted this code to grab all images in the asset pipeline. The problem is that I can see the image icon but the actual image itself doesn't show. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
@images = Dir.glob("app/assets/images/*.jpg")
<% @images.each do |image| %>
  <%= image_url "#{image}" %>
  <br>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What does the image local variable print out as in the loop?

Comment: something like this broken link picture: http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/google_broken_image_02_grid_base.png

Comment: Consider accepting the answer you got, if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3.2:

```
# controller
@images = Dir.glob('app/assets/images/*.jpg')

# view
<% @images.each do |image_path| %>
  <%= image_tag image_path.sub('app/assets/images/', '') %>
```